# Load form then show a message after defined period of time

Tags: c#, async-await, wait, thread-sleep, sharpdevelop

I am trying to make a game launcher where there is a limit of 10 minutes the it should close

Problem statement : I want to load the form , user should be able to do activities and then application should close after 10 minute

when i give any kind of sleep or wait in main method, the form itself is not loading i only get the messagebox ,then the application closes.

```
  public MainForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");

        Task.Run(async () =>
                 {
                    await Task.Delay(60000);
                 }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        MessageBox.Show("one minute left");

                    Task.Run(async () =>
                 {
                    await Task.Delay(60000);
                 }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    MessageBox.Show("time over");
                    Application.Exit();

    }
```

Comment: For reference, `var task = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(n); });` is functionally equivalent to just `var task = Task.Delay(n);` and avoids the compiler generated state machine you get from the `async` keyword.

Comment: Move the code to `Shown` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as follows:

```
Timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
Timer.Interval = TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS;
Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //desired behavior
}
```

System Timer runs async, after selected interval it triggers your method

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`) and then you can do this:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessageBox.Show("Welcome");

    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(x => MessageBox.Show("one minute left"));

    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("time over");
            Application.Exit();
        });
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer and a very brilliant solution indeed. I didn't think about `Reactive framework`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a task in a `fire and forget` fashion there is no need to call `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` because this will block the thread. So, basically, there is no point at all of all of these task that you have created. You could simply make use of the `Timer`s. As you are using `Windows Forms` you can use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or you can use `System.Threading.Timer`. I would use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to implement such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just schedule task from event handler:

```
private async void OnApplicationStarted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(9).TotalMilliseconds);

    MessageBox.Show("1 minute left");

    await Task.Delay((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);

    MessageBox.Show("time over");
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [Form.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) event with an async event handler. This will already show your form, so users will be able to see that the program has been started.

```
async void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
    // Notify the operator that the form is loading:
    this.ShowSplashScreen();

    // start the delay, but do not wait yet
    Task delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    // do other useful initializations, this might be shorter or longer than 5 seconds
    DoOtherInitializations();

    // now wait for the delay task to finish:
    await delayTask;

    this.HideSplashScreen();
}
```

Or an even nicer approach: show an startup-form which shows that you are starting, with only the possibility to cancel:

in class MainForm:

```
private async void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
     // show an intro screen while doing initializations:
     using (var startupForm = new FormStartup()
     {
          var dlgResult = startupForm.ShowDialog(this);

          if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
          {
               // operator cancelled starting up:
               this.Close();
          }
          else
          {
               // continue starting up
          }
    }
}

     }
}

class FormStartup
{
    public void FormStartup() {...}

    private async void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
    {
        Task delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        DoOtherInitializations();
        await delayTask;
    }
}
```